# Spring Boot: reduce configuration duplication in multi-document yml file

Tags: spring-boot

I have a multi-document configuration yml file that activates certain config based on the active spring profiles, like below:

```
# some common config

---
spring.config.activate.on-profile: abc & stage
# specific config for service abc in stage env

---
spring.config.activate.on-profile: def & stage
# specific config for service def in stage env

---
spring.config.activate.on-profile: xyz & stage
# specific config for service xyz in stage env

---
```

Say profiles `abc` and `def` use a kafka consumer but profile `xyz` doesn't. Is there a way I can abstract the common kafka configuration used in `abc` and `def` and reference it later in both? Something like this:

```
# some common config

---
some.label: kafka
# common kafka config

---
spring.config.activate.on-profile: abc & stage
include kafka
# specific config for service abc in stage env

---
spring.config.activate.on-profile: def & stage
include kafka
# specific config for service def in stage env

---
spring.config.activate.on-profile: xyz & stage
# specific config for service xyz in stage env

---
```

I know I could add the common kafka config in the "common config" section at the beginning, but that would also add it for profile `xyz` who doesn't need it.

I've also thought about creating a new profile altogether and include it when I call `abc` and `def` in order to combine the configuration (`spring.profiles.active=abc,kafka,stage`), but that seems redundant to me as `abc` and `def` won't work without the kafka config -- passing two profiles to get the functionality of one seems questionable...

Any other way to achieve this?

Note: my project uses Spring Boot version 2.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the way to go is using [profile groups](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles.groups). I would need to create a separate `kafka` config then group it to the wanted profiles like so:

```
# my common-to-all profiles config

---
spring.profiles: kafka
# my kafka config

---
spring.profiles: abc
spring.profiles.group.abc[0]: kafka
# my abc AND kafka config

---
spring.profiles: def
spring.profiles.group.def[0]: kafka
# my def AND kafka config

---
spring.profiles: xyz
# my xyz config (no kafka included)
```

This approach will:

1. Avoid config duplication between profiles `abc` and `def`. Kafka config will NOT be present in profile `xyz`
2. I still start my app with only one profile: `java -Dspring.profiles.active=abc -jar myapp.jar`